# Inno old installation and bespoke directories

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascal

I created a program and I'm using Inno to install. There is a working directory which currently set to mydocuments. This stores users media used in the program.

I desire to allow the user to change that directory so for example they could share it on for example a network drive. As long as everything is in the program this is all good.

However I'm looking at creating and updater. Perhaps adding media to that folder.

How can I query to see which folder this is currently set to? Then using that path as a variable append the files to that directory?

Would I need to set up an environmental variable on install? Create a set up text file to query and use some type of scripting or something simpler.

I know Java and Action Script but don't really know Pascal so not sure whats possible and just getting my head around it.

Comment: How does your program know which directory to use ? How are you storing the configuration of your program ?

Comment: Typically the folder where an application stores documents should be set to a per-user path.  As such it is not possible for a per-machine installer to do anything with it.

Comment: Currently the paths are hardcoded, in air there is a resolve path command which sets the users documents path. Im hoping to change the path to a network drive. Im providing some files with the installer. Im guessing the only other way is to start the app, get the user to choose the path and then copy those files over.